# Jquery - multiple settings inside addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm working on a simple Jquery plugin and i'm stuck on adding multiple classes to main selector through user defined options. It doesn't work if I use:

```
$("#testDiv").addClass(settings.addBG settings.addBorder);
```

But it does work if passing only one setting:

```
$("#testDiv").addClass(settings.addBG);
```

What am i missing? Progress preview avaliable here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ffmk1or)
thanks.

Comment: Setting.addBG+" "+setting.other

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addClass` accepts a string. You are passing two strings without concatenating which is causing a crash. Concatenate both strings to produce a string of both classes with a space in between.
Change statement in your code to

```
$("#testDiv").addClass(settings.addBG + " " + settings.addBorder);
```

Updated JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mpsingh2003/0ffmk1or/2/

Answer (score 1):

please try this one:

```
<div id="testDiv"><p>This is demo page</p></div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/0ffmk1or/5/)